# ASP.NET Crystal Report Arial Narrow Formatting Issue on different server

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I've a crystal report which is rendered by click of button on asp.net page.

The report looks 100% good on SIT environment. However, the same report has formatting issue on UAT_Pre_Prod environment. I've checked the fonts on this server which was missing Area Narrow which I installed. The report still looks all over the place.

Basically on UAT_Pre_Prod, the fonts are bold which it should not be, the text is cut-off.

I checked Crystal Report 2008 runtime environment and I also had a look at this thread but still doesn't work.

[Strange Crystal Report formatting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409978/strange-crystal-report-formatting-problem)

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this issue, the solution is to:

1. Install Font on Web Server.
2. Restart the web server (App Pool and Web Site restart did not work).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does rebooting the server solved your issue after installing the fonts?